# BulkInsertAsync get TimeOut when inserting one record

Tags: c#, nuget-package

i have a problem trying to insert data with BulkInsertAync :

```
 public async Task Insert(IList<AccountingRecordKeyParsingError> accountingRecordKeyParsingErrors)
        {
            await _context.BulkInsertAsync(accountingRecordKeyParsingErrors);
    }
```

this is my method, when i try to insert a specific record from a .txt i got a timeoutexception from BulkInsert. The data is small (it's just a simple record).

If i cut the .txt in half, the data pass without TimeOut.

If i set the timeout of the bulkinsert on "0" it work but this take a lot of time :

```
public async Task Insert(IList<AccountingRecordKeyParsingError> accountingRecordKeyParsingErrors)
        {
            await _context.BulkInsertAsync(accountingRecordKeyParsingErrors, o => o.BulkCopyTimeout = 0);
        }
```

I'm using EF 3.1 & BulkExtensions 3.1

Someone know why i get this timeout for a simple row ?

Comment: another operation is hammering your table perhaps? EF 3.1? BulkExtensions?
Can You update EF ? You want to get to 5 or above, EF 5 already is 10 years old!
those are a really good improvements your're missing out on. on a set You can simply do .AddRange => SaveChanges, why are you using this ancient technology? i wonder if you mean .net 3.1?

Comment: Well, it is EntityFrameworkCore 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I recommend forgetting the BulkExtensions this really is nothing which takes long for EF Core, so I suspect You get the error from the obsolete extension.
Obsolete only therein that EF Core does what you're trying to do well, without 'addons'

```
    DbSet<AccountingRecordKeyParsingError> _parsingErrors;

    public async Task Insert(IList<AccountingRecordKeyParsingError> accountingRecordKeyParsingErrors)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
            _parsingErrors.AddRange(accountingRecordKeyParsingErrors);
            SaveChanges();
        });
    }
```